# Timeshift restore to replacement SSD?

Tags: ssd

Ubuntu 20.04.

I think I know what to do here but would appreciate knowing any tips or if there's anything I've missed...

I have three SSDs, one with OS, one for backups and VMs and another mounted as my home directory.

The disk with home has died (after 6 months!) so I will replace. I know how to boot to a live USB and format with GParted and then I assume I'll just edit fstab to change the disk ID for my home folder from the dead one to the new one.

I then hope I can restore a Timeshift backup once up and running but don't know if the identification of a new disk will cause problems.

Any help appreciated!